# Data not being saved

Tags: javascript, jquery, save

I have input type with id = **dx_blog_posts_num**. After adding example number and clicking the button Save, the number is not being saved. Why ?

```
JavaScript:
  buttons: {
    'Save': function () {

       var num         = $(document).find('#dx_blog_posts_num').val();
       var image       = $(document).find('#dx_blog_featured_image').is(':checked');
       var excerpt    = $(document).find('#dx_blog_excerpt').is(':checked');

       parentDiv.attr('data-blog-image', image);
       parentDiv.attr('data-blog-excerpt', excerpt);

       var check    = parentDiv.find('.hidden').length;

       if(!check) {
        parentDiv.append('<div class="hidden">' + num + '</div>');
    }
    else{
     parentDiv.find('.hidden').html(num);
 }
 jQuery(this).dialog('destroy');
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'saved'?

Comment: Clicking the button save, and after that checking if the number is saved by seeing the input type. If the number is in the input type as a value, it is saved

Comment: what is "the input type"? what is `parentDiv`?